# Did Grothendieck-Serre write about toric varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I'm curious if Grothendieck or Serre wrote anything about toric varieties? Were they aware of the notion? I would much appreciate any references.

Comment: Serre is still alive, and I heard him lecturing about 10 years ago - not on algebraic geometry IIRC.

Comment: AFAIK toric varieties first appeared in http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1970_4_3_4_507_0.pdf, so it seems very likely that they were aware of the notion. But I doubt that either of them has written anything about toric varieties, Grothendieck was thinking about things that are "slightly" more broad, and Serre more or less switched to number theory around that time.

Comment: "slightly more broad." Such understatement. Wow.